# Cannot read property 'input' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> Javascript/HTML 2 part login error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, authentication

I am trying to create a 2 part login, 1st part where you enter the username, click login, and the login takes you to a page where you enter your password. I have a js function where I check if the username field is null, because I want to require the user to enter something in the text field before clicking the button redirects them to the second part of the login. However, I am getting an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: loginCheck is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

here is my code

```
var formhtml = '<div class="container"><label for="userNameBox"><b>Username </b></label><input type="text" id="userNameBox" placeholder="Enter Username"  required ="required"><br></br> <input type="button" id ="loginButton" value="Login"onclick="javascript:loginCheck()"/></div>'

function loginCheck(){
    var x = null;
    if(document.getElementById("userNameBox").value !=null){
        document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "myLogin.Part2";
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("username required");
        location.reload();
    }
}

      $('.login').click(function(e) 
       { 
         e.preventDefault();
         if ($('#loginbox').html() == '') 
             $('#loginbox').html(formhtml);
          
         $('#loginbox').show();
          
          
          return false; 
       });
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but a value of a form control element is never `null`, the condition will never be passed when you get the reference corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing a lot of Vanilla JavaScript and jQuery. Although that's not wrong, it might help you with development by choosing one or the other.

Like @Teemu said, the `value` of an input is never `null`. If it is empty than the value will be represented as an empty string `""`.

The `loginCheck` function will add an event listener to the `loginButton` element. But that element already has an `onclick` attribute which calls the `loginCheck` function. This will not run as you would like it to. Instead of both add an event listener with either `addEventListener` (Vanilla JavaScript) or with the `on` method (jQuery)

I've tried to convert your code so that it uses jQuery. Check it out and let me know if your problem has been resolved.

```js
const $document = $(document);
const $login = $("#login");
const $loginBox = $("#loginbox");

const $formElement = $(`
  <div class="container">
    <label for="userNameBox"><b>Username </b></label>
    <input type="text" id="userNameBox" placeholder="Enter Username" required="required"><br>
    <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Login"/>
  </div>
`);

$document.on("click", "#loginButton", function() {
  const $userNameBox = $("#userNameBox");

  if ($userNameBox.val() !== "") {
    location.href = "myLogin.Part2";
  } else {
    alert("username required");
    location.reload();
  }
});

$login.on("click", function (event) {
  if ($loginBox.children().length === 0) {
    $loginBox.append($formElement);
  }

  $("#loginbox").show();

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```